nginx reverse proxy returns 404 error when refreshing SPA application page
I have a nginx reverse proxy allowing access to a k8s pod that hosts a SPA application that is being served itself by a nginx web server inside the same pod. Whenever a page is refreshed, the reverse proxy returns a 404 error because the endpoint doesn't exist. How can I fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
REVERSE PROXY CONFIG:
`      location / {
          proxy_pass "http://pod-ui.default.svc.cluster.local/";
      }`

NGNIX WEB SERVER CONFIG:
`server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/www/html;
 }

 }`

I have tried to transform the 404 error into a 200 code and send it through a proxy pass pointing to my UI pod without success.
This was attempted by adding the following line to my reverse proxy server config.
`      error_page 404 =200 /;`

